# highcharts export server not working out of the box (Java)

Tags: java, highcharts, phantomjs

This question to readers who have used Highcharts Export Server:
I am trying to run Highcharts-3.0.2 as an export server in Java. I set it up with tomcat-7.0.41 and tried to use the example supplied (/demo). While the /demo page loaded successfully, on sending the request to `generate image` the log shows:

```
[ERROR] [http-bio-8080-exec-6 07:00:08] (SVGConverter.java:requestServer:109) POOL EXHAUSTED!!
```

I get the same message on every subsequent request.

On studying the code I found that when the application starts among others the following steps are executed:

1. AbstractPool calls on the objectfactory to create a new Server object and adds it to the blocking queue.

   ```
    T object = objectFactory.create();
    queue.add(object);
    poolSize.getAndIncrement();
   ```
2. The Server object is a new java.lang.Process object. After it is created it listens on the inputstream stream.

   ```
    process = new ProcessBuilder(commands).start();
    final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
    if (readLine == null || !readLine.contains("ready")) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Error, PhantomJS couldnot start");
   }
   ```

The `readLine()` blocks and the control is not returned and the Server instance is never added to the queue. Hence, the pool exhausted error.
So, there must be something on the `inputstream` to be read so that the control can proceed. My question is what is it that I have missed here?

**RESOLVED:** The problem was in `app.properties`. The parameter `script` in `app.properties` when left empty does not work in tomcat either contrary to the documentation. It is the convertor script `highcharts-convertor.js` which when executed in the process (see code above) returns a string on the `inputstream`.

**Edit** Jumped the gun too soon! The parameter `script` when left empty works as described in the documentation. I can see in the log:

```
[DEBUG] [pool-1-thread-1 01:46:35] (ServerObjectFactory.java:create:33) in makeObject,
C:\Users\...\webapp\phantomjs, 
C:/Users/.../workspaces/.../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/...highcharts-convert.js, 127.0.0.1
```

I do not understand what goes wrong when the command is constructed correctly with all the required parameters?
Explicitly giving the complete path to the `highcharts-convertor.js` for the parameter `script` in the `app.properties` works.

Is anybody experiencing this behavior?
I'm working in eclipse juno service release 2, buildid:20130225-0426, Highcharts-3.0.2, tomcat-7.0.41, win7 64bit

Comment: **RESOLVED** The problem was in app.properties. The parameter ´script´

Comment: Can you put up your app.properties settings for the script location and the phantomjs location?

Comment: # location of the phantomjs executable
    exec = C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Tools\\phantomjs-1.9.1-windows\\phantomjs 

    # location of convert script used by phantomjs
    script =

Answer (score 1):

For us using jetty or tomcat we had to explicitly give the location of both the files and, this is the kicker, make sure that all the files in the target directories listed in your app.properties files are not Read Only.

```
exec = C:/jetty-distribution-9.0.3.v20130506/webapps/Scripts/phantomjs/phantomjs.exe
script = C:/jetty-distribution-9.0.3.v20130506/webapps/Scripts/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js
```

The `C:/jetty-distribution-9.0.3.v20130506/webapps/Scripts/phantomjs` directory and all contents were not flagged as Read Only. This, for some reason, allowed the scripts and phatomjs.exe to be executable by the WAR.

Comment: well in the logs I see that the script `highchart-convert.js` gets picked up even if the parameter is left empty. But then the server doesn't work as expected. Explicity providing the path to the script does work. Hope somebody can explain this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The export-server for java is updated lately. We noticed many people had problems with the location of the phantomJS javascripts. All javascript files necessary for phantomjs are now unzipped to a temporary location and picked up from them for later use by the application.

With this you don't have to specify any longer the filelocation of the scripts.